# No such parameter?

Tags: struct, typedef, stm32

I think, this is a C related question.
This question is also asked in STM32 forum.
Kindly clear me the structure

Right at the moment, in AC6+Eclipse environment build error shows,

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7zs0.png)

```
C:/STM32_toolchain/common/Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/stm32f0xx_hal_adc.h:238:2: error: declaration for parameter 'ADC_HandleTypeDef' but no such parameter
}ADC_HandleTypeDef;
^
```

but when you search  stm32f0xx_hal_adc.h  file its written as

```
typedef struct
{
 ADC_TypeDef          *Instance; /*                      !< Register base address */
ADC_InitTypeDef                 Init;                              /*!< ADC required parameters */
DMA_HandleTypeDef         *DMA_Handle;            /*!< Pointer DMA Handler */
HAL_LockTypeDef                Lock;                         /*!< ADC locking object */
__IO uint32_t                          State;                       /*!< ADC communication state (bitmap of ADC states) */
__IO uint32_t                   ErrorCode;                      /*!< ADC Error code */
}ADC_HandleTypeDef;
```

Is it means, ADC_HandleTypeDef is not  declare in stm32f0xx_hal_adc.h?

Comment: This question is a MESS!!! You could by the least indent that piece of code there, and write the compilation errors within a narrow paragraph, so that we wouldn't have to scroll it sideways...

Comment: You mean I dont need to introduce anything? Cant you scroll it  left to right and right to left ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the definition *__IO* is declared in **core_cm0.h** if using CMSIS. You need to have this included in order to build HAL drivers.

Comment: Dont you think , C:\STM32_toolchain\common\Drivers\CMSIS\Include should be placed on project>properties>C/C++ Build>Setting>tool setting> includes?

Comment: Yes, that is a good start, you need to include core_cm0.h so that hal has access to its symbols.

Comment: I did so many days ago, but dont know why its showing  wrong? This there any upgrade issue of core_cm0.h?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include this file, even if the file in the project it will not be included if you do not enable the peripheral in the CubeMx. Because there is a file called stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h you will see all files that enabled by CubeMx and if not enabled it will be comment like bellow.

```
/**
  * @brief Include module's header file 
  */

#ifdef HAL_RCC_MODULE_ENABLED
  #include "stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.h"
#endif /* HAL_RCC_MODULE_ENABLED */
```

Comment: I think I did so, take a look this link,https://community.st.com/thread/34449-corrected-clock-setting-from-cubemx

Comment: Make sure the in the file stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h   the define Macro is exists  #define HAL_ADC_MODULE_ENABLED